# How use _emit in clang?

Tags: assembly, clang, inline-assembly, llvm-clang, emit

How to use [_emit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/inline/emit-pseudoinstruction?view=vs-2019) to emit bytes in clang compiler?

e.g(in MSVC):

```
#define emit_nop() _asm _emit 0x90
```

Comment: clang does not support `_emit` (at least not that I know about it).  You can use the `asm` keyword for a similar effect, but I wonder what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In compilers that support GNU extensions, there's no need for a separate `emit` keyword, just use GNU C inline assembly:

```
asm(".byte 0x90");   // implicitly   asm volatile
```

Or `.long` to emit a 32-bit constant.

GNU C inline asm is *not* parsed to detect clobbers or anything, so you could just `asm("nop");`

If you want to use instructions that modify registers, you normally need to tell the compiler about it with GNU C Extended inline assembly (output/input/clobbers).  See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, that's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @cYeR While it's the answer to your question, there is a good chance you're asking the wrong question and it's not what you needed.